# what is wrong with my javascript structure

Tags: javascript

I am really new on javascript. I want to read xml from an url and want to parse it on html. I have html and javascript codes like that:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
     <script>
       function loadXMLDoc(filename)
        {
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
             {
              xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
          else // code for IE5 and IE6
              {
                  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
          xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
          xhttp.send();
          return xhttp.responseXML;
        } 
        xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml");
        x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
        y=x.childNodes[0];
        document.write(y.nodeValue);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What is wrong ? thanks

Comment: In a nutshell,  `XMLHttpRequest`  is not allowed to access "foreign" domains, only your own.

Comment: also missing a semicolon after x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]

Comment: @georg so is there a way that you suggest to get xml from an url

Comment: You would need to proxy it with your own server side code... Or find a JSONP source... JSONP would be the best solution, but using something like PHP to grab the books.xml and then using javascript to query PHP for it

Comment: @ozi Does this helps.. http://jsfiddle.net/00sjfhep/ . this will work considering your browser being chrome set to flag `--disable-web-security`

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar your fiddle... is dead... I'd change your comment/link to a working example or something.

Comment: @Mayhem No..its works for me..I have mentioned the required condition which needs to be done first at clients browser, so as to see correct logs..

Comment: Try the following guide: http://www.sitepoint.com/php-xml-to-json-proxy/ as this will be your best approach.. And a simpler guide: http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/10/cross-domain-ajax-a-simple-workaround/

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar all you have done is confirmed what the very first comment already did..

Comment: @ozi i have written an answer for you, as to save you a headache.. Please do read it and take note, this will set you on the right path.

Comment: @georg what is your suggestion about these 2 answers

Comment: @ozi: the only reliable way to get content from foreign resources is to do that server side, i.e.  your server, and not JS client, talking to another server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the standard method to do this task:

Since people keep going along the path of trying to use cross domain for something other than JSONP... **IT WILL NOT WORK!**

The following code below is an example of what will work, as your server is allowed to get content from other network locations being its more controlled.. Your browser on the other hand can only receive JSONP  or PLAIN TEXT... Most google results should explain this as well..

**YOUR ONLY OPTION**

Is to use a **PROXY** of some form to obtain what your trying to access, So you only have three choices here.

- Use JSONP or Plain Text
- Use a Proxy or some other method that is local to your server/website/script/page
- Keep trying to use examples posted here after being told cross domain rules apply.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function loadXMLDoc(sURL) {
    $.post( "myproxy.php", { requrl: sURL }).done(function( data ) {
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
        document.write(data);
    });    
}
```

PHP: myproxy.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
    $file = file_get_contents($_POST['requrl']);
    echo $file;
?>
```

Please note that is you plan to use this with other types of content then you will need to change/remove the header line.

**YOUR BROWSER ALLOWS YOU TO AJAX XML FROM OTHER WEBSITES**

If this is the case, then you need to replace or update your web browser..

**THE ABOVE SOLUTION IS NOT COMPLEX**

This is virtually copy and paste code ready to go, The JS function will return the result/data/content in the three most know ways...

The PHP script is a copy and paste as well.. So if you have PHP installed.

All you would need to do is create a new text file in the same location as your html document and name it as "myproxy.php" and this example will work.

Comment: That code you have posted under javascript,  is not at all javascript..Neither OP has tagged `jQuery`

Comment: Ahhh Rakesh... Read the answer... THERE IS NO SOLUTION WITH JUST JAVASCRIPT! I've used jquery to give a cleaner example showing that the Javascript side of things is purely a network request

Comment: Your welcome, i would just rather see people set on the right path from the start. PHP itself is a common server side language that is free. But if you have apache, you most likely have PHP nd the above code is about as easy as it can be done, of course expanding it would be desired.

Answer (score -2):

This is a proper XmlHttpRequest with a callback function to handle your XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(url){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                callbackFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function callbackFunction(response){

    if (window.DOMParser){  //  Non IE
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xml_doc = parser.parseFromString(response,"text/xml");
    }else{                  // Internet Explorer
        var xml_doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xml_doc.async = false;
            xml_doc.loadXML(response);
    }

    //  Do something with your 'xml_doc' object variable here

    console.log(xml_doc)    //  Debugging only.. to see the XML in the browser console for your own reference

    var x = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
    var y = x.childNodes[0];
    document.write(y.nodeValue);
}

// Call the function to begin code execution
loadXMLDoc('http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working code so you can just erase what you have and put this directly in place of it. Good luck!

If you're planning on hosting the file on your own server to access via XHR, the code I offered is intended for that. If w3schools.com had a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header on the XML file your are requesting, it would also work. But they don't. So you need to have the XML file in a place where your browser's security will let you access it (same domain origin as your webpage). Otherwise your browser will continue to block the resource with a 'cross-origin-request-blocked' error in the console.

Comment: By the way, someone mentioned 'missing' semicolons.  They are not required in javascript to denote a termination of a line of code.  Rather, javascript treats 'line-breaks' as the end of a line and the semicolon is optional... assuming you don't need to squish two commands onto a single line.

Comment: Thank you but when I try it, I can not see returning value. should I change something in code

Comment: What browser are you using and have you taken a look at the browser console when you run the code?

Comment: I am using firefox and and this code (document.write(y.nodeValue);) should write value right ?

Comment: I mentioned the semicolon just as a side note. If you use them.. then use them at every location they should be used.. Syntax is Syntax... Now as for this answer.. It it still triggers the cross-domain rule... I'm guessing you tested this locally then just changed the url before posting.. This is not a correct of valid answer!

Comment: That is correct.  I'm using Safari and it's writing 'Everyday Italian' on my document.  Do you know how to check your code with the built-in Firefox console? The XML request may be getting a 'same-origin' error because the file you are accessing is not stored on the same computer your code is running on.  The firefox console will tell you if that is the problem if you have the console open.

Comment: @FactoryAidan I look the log and it says 'cross origin request blocked'

Comment: @FactoryAidan then your browser is broken and prone to exploits! Trust me here, i work alot with ajax and cross domains.. This above code does not work! if it works in your browser, i suggest you upgrade / replace it! ...Asking if i know how to use a console... lol.. Further more if you want cross browser support...  read up on this subject...

Comment: Mayhem, you gotta calm down bud.  My last comment was not for you. Anyway, back to being helpful.  @ozi  the 'cross origin request blocked' means that your browser is properly sending the XmlHttpRequest and getting a response back.  However, w3schools.com does not allow cross-origin-requests.  The only way around this is to open up your browser's security like this guy explains:

http://dirolf.com/2007/06/enabling-cross-domain-ajax-in-firefox.html

but like he says, you really shouldn't do that.

The other option is to download the XML file from w3schools.com for access by your own computer.

Comment: By opening your browser up, your only allowing your browser to view this.. If your looking for something that will work for all visitors to a website or in general multiple users.. This needs to be considered.... and simply there are days on SOF where no matter how much you help people are still blinded by trying to find a hack vs taking a simple and correct path.. Become a good clean coder or a dirty loop hole opener?

Comment: ozi , I agree with @Mayhem. If you're planning on hosting the file on your own server to access via XHR, the code I offered is intended for that. If w3schools.com had a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header on the XML file your are requesting, it would also work.  But they don't.  The only options to accomplish your project are the ones we mentioned in these comments... or the pretty genius method offered in PHP by 'Mayhem' if that is in your ability.  You have two really excellent coders working on your question and I believe we have taken your answer as far as it will go. Again, good luck.

Comment: Just a side note on semicolons and where i picked up the habit of always using them, mostly due to other languages.. but when transferring scripts between windows/linux. Certain editors would not pick up the line breaks correctly, it would render in the editor with lines due to the carriage return but the actual line terminator n was removed / changed.. Fixed the the editor to change the encoding. But my base reasons to why i always swear by semicolons. BUT agreed that they are not required when it comes to end of line for js

Comment: @Mayhem, well said sir.